# Nvidia drivers stooped working on update 20.04.3

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, graphics

Sadly I was not able to resolve this one. I wish I could delete this question without being penalized. This was my main workstation and I was using it for work. I could not wait any longer. I had to reinstall the system.

---

Everything when fine for more than 2 years. After the last Ubuntu update, my system stopped recognizing the monitor and no matter what drivers I'm using I'm stuck with

- unknown monitor
- 1024x768 resolution

My system configuration

```
bogdan@bogdan-pc ~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
bogdan@bogdan-pc ~ $ uname -r
5.13.0-22-generic
bogdan@bogdan-pc ~ $ lspci | grep VGA
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1)
bogdan@bogdan-pc ~ $ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I have tried switching between different versions of drivers and also the nouveau drivers.
I have also noticed that when installing a particular driver the package manager picks the 20.04.1 version and my system is 20.04.3.

Last time I tried installing
Install command

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

Snippet from install logs

```
Setting up libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 (470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-470:i386 (470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-470:amd64 (470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-470:i386 (470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470 (470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64 (470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386 (470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
```

I have also tried

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Please help me out

Comment: First, make sure the latest Nvidia driver is installed by running the following commands: `sudo apt update` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` This will automatically install the correct driver version and configuration.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` Just in case I tried them again.
I'm still not able to change the refresh rate and resolution.

Comment: Check that secure boot is still off in the UEFI settings too.

Comment: Which Nvidia card?

Comment: I use GeForce GTX 1080. 
Secure boot is off and also UEFI settings.

Comment: `dkms status` please maybe it is not bild

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to reinstall Ubuntu. This is the main working workstation and the time, in this case, is too expensive. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Try going to additional drivers and choosing your Card

Answer (score -1):

i have the same issue it looks like i resolved it by

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-470 --purge
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo init 6
```

Comment: I tried also this suggestion but sadly it did not help. I'm still stuck.

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck with suspend crashing, and discovered hints toward updating graphics drivers. Couldn't change or update them, and I noted also that system updates were lagging.

If this (from the post above) doesn't work

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-470 --purge
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

...and you get errors that software cannot be downloaded or certificates are outdated... so there may be a problem with software sources.

I found out that the servers had changed for Ubuntu 20.04.03 in some point in the end of 2021, and after some digging I found out that my /etc/apt/sources.list was outdated.

Maybe because of upgrade, not clean install (could have been my own tampering too), the national versions of the servers were referenced (fr.archive.ubuntu.com) instead of plain archive.ubuntu.com).

You can find the correct sources.list here: https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170

I also updated the CA sertificates after correcting sources.list:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
sudo apt-get upgrade
```